# Trouble making nginx works with symfony in subdirectory

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm trying to setup Symfony 4 next to an already working wordpress site with nginx. Wordpress should manage the homepage at

> https://www.my.domain

and the blog posts under

> https://www.my.domain/conseils

The symfony application should take over for anything under

> https://www.my.domain/app

I've read the default documentation bot [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) aswell as some troubleshooting made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775627/symfony-app-in-a-subdirectory-in-nginx-for-an-existing-site). Furthermore, it seems REALLY close to that answered question but with nginx instead of apache: [Symfony4 routing inside a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895202/symfony4-routing-inside-a-subfolder)

The fact is i still cant manage to make it working. Here's my current site.conf which gives me a 404, but i cant really find some helpful log even with the debug option enabled in nginx.

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name www.my.domain;
    root /var/www/my.domain/html;


    #symfony location block
    location /app {
        alias /var/www/my.domain/app/public;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri /app/public/index.php/$1 last;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;


        error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
    }

    #Wordpress location block
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;



        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg)$ {
         expires max;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

    }

}
```

Lastly i tried something found [here](https://gist.github.com/marcw/2bebd7094b649a627a171ee1d5e34b26). This times, it gives me the following symfony routing error: No route found for "GET /app".
Below the conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name www.my.domain;
    root /var/www/my.domain/html;


    # Symfony location block
    location /app {
        alias /var/www/my.domain/app/public;
        index index.php;

        rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri @symfonyFront;


    }
        set $symfonyRoot /var/www/my.domain/app/public;
        set $symfonyScript index.php;
        location @symfonyFront {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $symfonyRoot/$symfonyScript;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app/$symfonyScript;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /app$uri?$args;
        }

    #Wordpress location block
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;



        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg)$ {
         expires max;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my.domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my.domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

In both cases, the wordpress is working as intended. Homepage and blog posts are showing when expected. The symfony app however isnt. For the former cas, i got a 404 when visiting my.domain/app and the latter gives me a symfony routing error. That means i'm actually hitting SF front controller. And i got the kernel stack trace saying the route app/ is not found within symfony. And that's absolutely correct since i expect symfony to work under that directory and it should not be user for the routing.

At this point i'm not even sure which one makes me close to the desired result. Any tip would be appreciated!

EDIT:
etc/nginx/error.log with debug activated show many lines but this one caught my attention:

> 2019/08/15 18:11:42 [alert] 6929#6929: *5 "alias" cannot be used in
>   location "/app" where URI was rewritten, client: 86.252.250.94,
>   server: www.my.domain, request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "www.my.domain"

And when i got the route not found error, i got that (which is expected) in the symfony log:

> [2019-08-15 18:26:00] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /app"" at /var/www/my.domain/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 141 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /app\" at /var/www/my.domain/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:141, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/app/\". at /var/www/my.domain/app/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/Dumper/CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:70)"} []

EDIT2: i've added the

> fastcgi_split_path_info ^/app(.+.php)(/.+)$;

without noticeable change.
Interestingly enough, when i replaced the rewrite directive with "last" instead of "break" it displays the 404 page from wordpress.

Comment: to me, it's not really clear at all, what isn't working and what is your objective. My advice would be to spend some paragraph with example paths and uris, of which some should be wordpress-related, I guess, and with some comments on what is working (for each url perhaps) and what isn't. also if wordpress and symfony are supposed to work side-by-side, you probably should explain what you mean by that and add the nginx conf for wp as well? maybe there's some unwanted interaction?

Comment: Thank your for your feedback @Jakumi. I've edited several parts of the question, and commented the conf file to make it more clear. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: imho, greatly improved. my advice for the first part is, to actually include: `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` always (check, that it's located there, and named this way! my line is `include fastcgi.conf;`). however, you should absolutely check the nginx error_log files and also the fpm log files (if you defined those in your fpm pool, otherwise you probably should enable them temporarily) - just to find out, which file is actually being accessed (and possibly not found). finally: unless your symfony is explicitly set up differently, config isn't read from .env but from server env.

Comment: for the environment issues, you should really check the var/log/prod.log in your symfony dir.

Comment: I've added some error logs @Jakumi. and updated the site.conf file. I've the feeling it may be related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895202/symfony4-routing-inside-a-subfolder

Comment: hmhmhm ... okay, so apparently symfony doesn't get, that it's supposed to run on a different base directory. The base can be set in the router_context. this is usually only necessary for commands, but you might try if this also does stuff for the standard routing: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html - so `router.request_context.base_url: /app` ... or maybe without the slash even. but the actual problem is, that symfony thinks it's running on the domain, and not in the app sub-dir. i.e. your rewriting doesn't work. this is pretty much an nginx question then -> serverfault

Comment: according to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info it might be, that the fastcgi_split_path_info regex is `^/app(.+\.php)(/.+)$` in your symfony-specific location block, or a rewrite ... http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite like `rewrite /app(.*) $1 last;` ... but I'm really no nginx expert

Comment: i give it a try and keep you informed. Thank you :)

Comment: I've edited one last time @Jakumi. I'm heading to serverfault in case they have any idea too. Thanks for your time!